# Select the Largest Z property of a list of Objects where the Date is a specific Date

Tags: c#

I have an Object which has a Date Property and a Z property.

```
class myClass
{
    DateTime theDate;
    int Z =0;
}
```

I Create a List of those objects based off of a SQL Query
then I need to select the Largest Z value for a specific Date.

```
public int GetMaxZ(List<myClass> myClasses, DateTime date)
{
    int z=0;
    z = select Z from c in myClasses
        where c.theDate=date 
    //Select the Max somehow
    return z;
}
```

Obviously the code does not allow for selecting the Highest Z of the specific Date

I had thought of selecting all the same date, then iterate through those but that does not sound like a solid practice.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myClasses.Where(x => x.theDate == date)
.Select(x => x.Z)
.OrderByDescending(x => x)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `First()` could be used instead of `FirstOrDefault()` if the list will always have some items.

Comment: Worked like a Charm.  I feel obligated to Try Gusman's solution....  It matched my example as well, so Gonna test it now

Answer (score 1):

FIrst of all, that code doesn't even compile as the select is an IQueryable, but you try to use as int.

But, for your luck, as it's an IQueryable you can just use Max():

```
public int GetMaxZ(List<myClass> myClasses, DateTime date)
{
    var z = from c in myClasses
            where c.theDate=date
            select Z;

    return z.Max();
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much my second thought, though you didn't iterate through them you selected the Max, which is good to know for the future.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, my IDE is not recognizing the select, from,where key words.  Do I need a Using statement.  And I know they were in my example, I mean no offense from the question just trying to figure it out

Comment: Try it now, your original linq code was not well formatted, I updated the answer